# Adding a list of email addresses to a UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, xamarin.ios

I have a UITextField that I want to display a pre-defined list of email addresses, then allow the user to select one or two before going to SendMail (MFMailComposeViewController).

I have tried appending "\n\r" but it still displays in one line.

How do I get it to display a list of addresses?  (Obj-C is ok, but I'm using Monotouch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a UITextView, as you are showing more than one of something.

Comment: Works... now how do I select a row?  or can't I?

Comment: select a row? You need to use a UITableView for selecting rows.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a UITableView and not a UITextView. If you want to ship around cumbersome UITableView implementations, try Monotouch.Dialog (https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog).

René